# How can I see whether a github fork might be further than the original?

Tags: git, github

Sometimes I face the situation that a not actively maintained github project has several forks.

I would like to investigate these forks whether they have any features I could be interested in.

Is there any possibility to see whether

- any of the forks has any / further commits than the original project
- or pull requests
- or issues

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try and use a tool like [`techgaun/active-forks`](https://github.com/techgaun/active-forks) which will  find the most active forks of a repository.

You can sort the result by last push and get an idea of fork recent activity

Example: https://techgaun.github.io/active-forks/index.html#rafalense/Plus-Messenger